# jetty Persistent Sessions

Tags: java, session, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm using persistent sessions with jetty, as described here:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/using-persistent-sessions.html

Sessions are normally saved and restored after a stop/restart.

This is true as long as the application is not abruptly terminated, i.e. not calling the `stop()` method on my `Server` instance, even though the file where the session has been persisted looks fine.

I'd like to be able to restore my sessions, to the maximum extent possible, even in the case of a sudden halt of the system.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: N.B. in jetty 9.4 session management changed and this problem no longer applies